# Mocking dates in AngularJS / Jasmine tests

Tags: unit-testing, date, angularjs

I have a directive that initializes the Date object several times in several functions. 
When Unit testing the individual functions I can handle stubbing the date like this:

```
(function (global) {
  var NativeDate = global.Date;

  global.stubDateConstructor = function (fakeDate) {
      global.Date = function () {
          global.Date = NativeDate;
          return fakeDate;
      }
  }
}(this));

// ageInYears()
it("should return the age in years of the person given his/her birthdate", function() {
    stubDateConstructor(new Date('2010/01/01'));
    expect(ageInYears('01-01-1990')).toBe(20);
    stubDateConstructor(new Date('2010/01/01'));
    expect(ageInYears('01-01-1900')).toBe(110);
});
```

For unittesting the directive itself, which calls the ageInYears and several other similar functions this isn't going to work as I after one call to Date() stubDateConstructor will have reset Date() to the real Date object.

Is there a native way in AngularJS / Jasmine to handle these situations, or should I look into Sinon e.g.?

Comment: it's dawning on me now that I might have to initialize date once and pass that to the functions requiring it..maybe that's the best solution?

Comment: I'm a fan of Timecop.js myself. Any library with functions like Timecop.travel and Timecop.freeze gets my approval.

Comment: it looks like sinon.js might also provide time mocking that applies to dates (dependent on browser support) http://sinonjs.org/docs/#clock

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Jasmine (2.2) Clock can mock dates and time.

http://jasmine.github.io/2.2/introduction.html#section-Mocking_the_Date

For example (from the docs):

```
it("mocks the Date object and sets it to a given time", function() {
  var baseTime = new Date(2013, 9, 23);
  jasmine.clock().mockDate(baseTime);

  jasmine.clock().tick(50);
  expect(new Date().getTime()).toEqual(baseTime.getTime() + 50);
});
```

Comment: thanks, looks like it didn't exist back when I asked but seems the right tool now

Answer (score 12):

A straightforward solution would be to create an Angular `Dates` service that provides `Date` objects for you - it might even just have a single method - `Dates.now()` - that just sends back the current date by returning `new Date()`. You then use this service whenever something needs to get the current date.

This then allows you to inject a different `Dates` service when unit testing, for example one that always returns a specific date of your choice when called, rather than the current time.

Comment: So simple, my mind was wandering to all sorts of silly overly complex scenarios. Thanks bro!

Answer (score 1):

angular.mock.TzDate would a better native alternative here. this comes as a helper from angular mocks and truly safe guard your test from the system timezone or any other dependencies

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/type/angular.mock.TzDate

this plays well with Jasmine or mocha

Answer (score 0):

I was able to mock using a combination of [sinon's fake timers](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#clock-api)  to mock the window's timers and angular's [mock interval service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24interval) for angular to recognize time changes .  Here, the countDownService under test makes use internally of both javscript `Date` and angular's normal [interval service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24interval) Something like:

```
  describe('when start time was 3000 milliseconds and 1001 milliseconds have passed', function() {
    var startTime;
    var elapse;
    beforeEach(function(){
      this.clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
      startTime = 3000;
      elapse = 1001;
    });

    var elapseMillis = function(intervalMock,sinonClock,millis){
      sinonClock.tick(millis);
      intervalMock.flush(millis);
    };

    it('elapsedMillis + timeRemainingMillis should == startime', 
      inject(function($rootScope,$interval,countdownService) {
        countdownService.startTimer(startTime);
        elapseMillis($interval,this.clock,elapse);
        //jasmine clock does not mock Date
        //see https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/issues/361
        var elapsedMillis = countdownService.getElapsedMillis();
        var timeRemainingMillis = countdownService.getTimeRemainingMillis();
        expect(elapsedMillis + timeRemainingMillis).toEqual(startTime);
        expect(elapsedMillis).toEqual(elapse);
    }));

    afterEach(function(){
      this.clock.restore();
        startTime = 0;
        elapse = 0;
    });
  });
```

You'll want to make sure and include sinon js's `sinon-timers-1.8.1.js` in your karma.conf.js files property, too.