# How to mock constructors in AngularJS(in particular Date() constructor)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to test a function that accepts millisSinceEpoch and returns the time if the date is the current date else returns the time.

```
getLocaleAbbreviatedDatetimeString: function(millisSinceEpoch) {
  var date = new Date(millisSinceEpoch);
  if (date.toLocaleDateString() == new Date().toLocaleDateString()) {
    // The replace function removes 'seconds' from the time returned.
    return date.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/:\d\d /, ' ');
  }
  return date.toLocaleDateString();
```

I'm hoping to test this by mocking the Date() constructor, but I'm not sure how to mock a constructor using 'prototype'?

Also, is there a better way to test this ?

Comment: I like Timecop.js for everything Test-Date-ish (https://github.com/jamesarosen/Timecop.js)

Comment: Could you explain what that if statement is doing there? To me it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Anzeo if the millisSinceEpoch represents today's date, return the time otherwise return the date. Similar to the timestamp gmail uses.

Comment: You might want to have a look at my answer to [Monkeypatch the JavasScript date object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21591078/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

I do my best not to use `Date` or `Math.random` within my code.

I create services replacing them, this way I can mock to my hearts content by simply activating the mock module.

```
angular.module('my.date',[])
    .value('Date', Date);

angular.module('my.mock.date',[])
    .value('Date', function(){
        // mock Date code
    });
```

(of course, you don't need to mock all of `Date`s functionality, only the parts that you use...)

See also [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2030#issuecomment-13737778) issue on angular. And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086320/mocking-dates-in-angularjs-jasmine-tests) on stackoverflow.